# how to write command inside command

Tags: linux, perl, unix

im using system command in perl to execute su command like this

```
system("su -");
```

The above command works fine..

But if my command is this

```
su -c "echo hello"
```

Then how do i embed this command into system command of perl?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simple need quote escaping, either by using a different quote set:

```
system('su -c "echo hello"');
```

Or by "escaping" the quotes themselves:

```
system("su -c \"echo hello\"");
```

Or as individual arguments, as `mu is too short` points out:

```
system("su", "-c", "echo hello");
```

Answer (score 6):

[`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) can work with a list rather than a single string:

> **system LIST**
>   **system PROGRAM LIST**
>
> [...] Note that argument processing varies depending on the number of arguments. If there is more than one argument in LIST, or if LIST is an array with more than one value, starts the program given by the first element of the list with arguments given by the rest of the list.

So you could avoid the nested quote problems with this:

```
system('su', '-c', 'echo hello')
```

Comment: This is the safer route. It doesn't needlessly involve a shell.